# How to configure "webpack"? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I make a js-task using modules. I also use module bundler - Webpack.
I try to bundle all modules and start it. But in browser console I get error:

[image: Error which I got]

You can see all my project files by clicking at the link below:
https://github.com/AntonPozharitskiy/ITECHART/tree/master/THIRD_TASK

I don't use any module bundler's before so I don't what's happened and how to make it works. I will be glad to any help

Comment: you are missing the concept of an es module. Read more about it and your code will work with webpack. http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html

Comment: @PlayMa256 it's don't help me but thank you for advice :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have the solve of my own question.
Just add './' before and '.js' after name of script in 'require' brackets :)
Node JS logic killed me.